# IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3: Can we edit the custom attributes of User Identity Object [MobileFirst Session]

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

With the help of the following API calls,

```
1. WL.Server.setActiveUser
2. WL.Server.getCurrentUserIdentity
```

We can create user session and get the user identity properties respectively.

I have a scenario where I want to update the properties[custom attributes] in the user identity object when the session is active.

I couldn't find an API which can do this task.

Is there any way/work-around available.

Answer (score 1):

In general activated userIdentity is immutable. Try this, it might work

```
var userIdentity = WL.Server.getActiveUser("realm");
userIdentity[propName] = newValue;
WL.Server.setActiveUser("realm", null);
WL.Server.setActiveUser("realm", userIdentity);
```